# How to copy settings into a new profile?

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

I have a bug: I couldn't drag and drop windows. I reinstalled firefox and created a new profile - and it was gone.

Now, how the heck should I copy all the settings and plugins and plugins settings, but only those which doesn't cause the bug???

(This sux)

Answer (score 1):

Open the old `prefs.js` and the new `prefs.js` and copy paste the settings you need into the `prefs.js`.

I use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en) for this.

Comment: Hem its 277 kb big, and what about the rest of settings and addons?

Comment: only copy the settings of addons you've reinstalled. Ignore the rest.

Comment: use the old Profile with Firefox again, and here you can open the Adblock Plus options and export the settings. Other Addons also offer this.